# Chrome won't load webfont

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webfonts

Checking out a website I built a while ago, I noticed a new bug:

A couple of my webfonts won't load. But only in Chrome. Other browsers manage to load the font just fine.

Looking at the network section in devtools gives me some interesting info:

In the status column of the network report, I see "(failed) net::ERR_FAILED".

But if I look at the http conversation I can see that the font is requested, and the server responds with an http status of '200'.

Why is Chrome telling me that the font is both available to the network, and unavailable due to a network error?

Comment: Does the console provide you any clues?  Are you loading an https page, but loading fonts over http?

Comment: Hi @PaulProgrammer. I did (and still) suspect https might be the issue. But the site is loading over https. The requests for the fonts specify https. There's no protocol mismatch.

Comment: Are the fonts on exactly the same domain as the page?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer yes.